# How to delete a bunch of the same text on different JSON.files?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I’m wondering if there is a way to delete a bunch of code that was generated on my json files, like I have 1000 json files generated and I want to delete a link that I mistakenly wrote. Is there a quick way to delete that link from 1000 json files rather than having to go one by one to deleting it?

Comment: if you want to modify all files you have to open/modify/save then all, write a simple node script to read JSON, find the link, remove it from the object and save back as JSON

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I’m actually really new to coding and using visual studio code. Could you please provide steps? It would be so helpful!

Comment: SO is not a Programming/Homework service, this is a good project to start learning Node.js, for each step there are tons of tutorials

Comment: Definitely not asking you to do my homework, just asking to provide clearer steps to the comment you made me in the first place. But thanks.

Comment: a simpler breakdown as in the first comment is not possible

Comment: have you edited 1000 files by hand? How long did  it take you? Where you unable to write a script to do this for you?

Comment: Thank you so much but I found the solution. :)

Comment: if you post the solution as an answer other people benefit from it. SO is a two way system. It is not to only solve your questions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.